# What is the formula for proportions of elements using perspective and translateZ?

Tags: css, perspective, translate3d

I would like to do the following: Given a container with perspective and an inner element with a translateZ value I'd like to "pull it up" with translateY in order to visually touch the top of the surrounding container: http://jsfiddle.net/8R4ym/129/

Is there some kind of formula that, given the perspective value of a container, the width and height of an element and it's Z-translation I can get to that kind of "top" calculation? I have been playing around with it but I can't seem to find some rules for it, as it seems that those are all variables.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes!

There's actually quite a simple formula for finding the offset - the [3d Projection article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Diagram) on Wikipedia has a diagram and the formula.

The formula is `bx = ax * bz / az` where:

- `ax` is the original distance from the transform origin point
- `az` is the perspective + the negative `translateZ`
- `bz` is the perspective

and this will give you:

- `bx` - the new distance from the transform origin point

So, you need to know:

- `bz` : the `perspective` (eg: `1000px`)
- `ax` : the offset from the transform origin point, eg: if the origin point is 50% then this needs to be the element's `top` relative to the center of the parent element (`parent.height/2 + element.top`) -- let's say `-500px`
- `z` : the element's `translateZ` (eg: `-600px`)
- `az` is then `bz + z * -1`, in this case: `1000 + (-600 * -1) = 1600`

so the formula is: `-500 * 1000 / 1600 = -312.5`

The element is offset vertically `-312.5px` from the origin, whereas originally it was offset `-500px`, the difference between the two number is what you'll need to add to the old `top` value to get the equivalent new value.

This formula also works for the Y axis.

I put together a quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/trolleymusic/xYRgx/

Comment: Oh, and the example is -webkit prefixed - sorry.

Comment: I was working on this myself and created the following pen if anyone is interested: http://codepen.io/aaron/pen/lvrba

Comment: @Trolleymusic maybe you are the one who knows [the formular i'm looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578101/formular-to-calculate-width-height-relative-to-parent-of-container-with-transl). I really hope so (+100 bounty available)!

Answer (score 0):

There might be (don't know offhand) but have you tried changing `-webkit-transform-origin:;` first to see if you can simply apply the transformation along the top so the element appears where you want it without translating it?

Comment: I tried that but I guess it does not affect anything because it's translating into the z-axis...