# Horizontal CSS only parallax effect with layers greater than 100vw

Tags: html, css, parallax, css-transforms

## How to bootstrap a site with horizontal *CSS only parallax effect*?

**Requirements**

- CSS only parallax
- parent layer must have width/height == 100vw/100vh
- child layers must have width/height > 100vw/100vh
- child layers must visually align 100% with parent layers width

  - by now the child layers technically do have 100% of parents width but due to the `perspective` they visually don't appear to take 100% of parents width
- child layers (except the first) must have a top offset relative to its parent
- results must base on calculations to have maximum flexibility
- must be cross browser solid (at least newest version of majors)

[image]

### What I have done so far

Actually this question is a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578101/formular-to-calculate-width-height-relative-to-parent-of-container-with-transl).
Here's a PEN with my current mockup state in [SASS](https://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/EvWEyb?editors=0100) or [CSS](https://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/WEdqQO?editors=0100).

#### Working Simulated Example (jQuery)

In JavaScript its quite simple to achieve what I'm looking for. [So here is a PEN](https://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/gxzeXY?editors=0100)  that simulates the effect I'd like to mimic with CSS.

#### Already known Issues

The issue I'm most concerned about by now is the fact, that browser seem to render this scenario differently. See screenshot of browser window (chrome vs ff) scrolled to the right bottom corner below. But I hope this could be avoided.

[image]

### There are so many parallax tutorials out there. Why is this different?

Actually I researched really a lot but didn't find not even one description how to implement **horizontal parallax** (means the child layers have a width > 100vw). Of course there are [horizontal parallax scroll tuts](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/practical-css-parallax/horizontal-scroll/) out there. But they all have one in common: the child layer widths are always <= 100vw - and thats actually the difference.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

#projection {
  -webkit-perspective: 1px;
  perspective: 1px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 0 0;
  perspective-origin: 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.pro {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);
  transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
}

.pro--1 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(4) translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(-3px);
  transform: scale(4) translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(-3px);
  width: 110%;
}

.pro--2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(3) translate(0px, 1em) translateZ(-2px);
  transform: scale(3) translate(0px, 1em) translateZ(-2px);
  width: 110%;
}

.pro--3 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2) translate(0px, 2em) translateZ(-1px);
  transform: scale(2) translate(0px, 2em) translateZ(-1px);
  width: 110%;
}

.pro {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px orange;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.pro--2 {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px green;
  color: green;
}

.pro--3 {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="projection">
  <div class="pro pro--1">pro--1</div>
  <div class="pro pro--2">pro--2</div>
  <div class="pro pro--3">pro--3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain I've gotten exactly what you're targeting, but I've at least got a step forward for you. In [this article](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) on pure-css parallax sites, there was an update regarding working around webkit related bugs by using `perspective-origin-x: 100%` and `transform-origin-x: 100%`.

If I apply this in both x and y directions to your current mockup case with sass, I end up changing just `#projection` and `.pro` to be like this:

```
#projection
  perspective: $perspective + 0px
  perspective-origin: 100% 100%
  height: 100%
  overflow: auto
  width: 100%

.pro
  @include projection()
  height: 100%
  position: absolute
  transform-origin: 100% 100%
  transform-style: preserve-3d
  width: 100%
```

And the parallax behavior starts to look much more like I might expect. Here is the final pen: https://codepen.io/kball/pen/qPbPWa/?editors=0100

Comment: Dear @kball thank you very much for taking some time on this. Actually your edit does appear slightly better in the end and therefor would be worth to be used in a lot of use cases. But technically its not a step forward as it doesn't solve issues but only shifts them. I do want to align all `.pro`-containers exactly 100% with the parent `#projection`-container. Technically the `.pro`s have a width of 100% but due to the perspective they don't appear to have 100% of the parents width (which is what I'd like to achieve). Anyway thanks again for spending time...

Comment: By the way I did read the whole series of http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/